# AG-grid : Changing the font color of parent row when child row cell is edited

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-validation

I need to change the font-color of the parent row to red when any cell of the child row is edited.
Also the cellStyle for various cells of the child row is displayed in red color when the data is not correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using redraw API provided by ag grid. Just call the API after the cell value is changed.